# Как можно сделать приватный репозиторий публичным на gitHub

Tags: github

Есть приватный репозиторий на `GitHub`. Хочу сделать его публичным для публикации на `GitPages`. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Справа в меню зайти в настройки "Settings" затем вкладка "Options" и в самом низу "Make this repository public".

**Обновлено:**
В разделе `Settings` > `General` в самом низу находим группу `Danger Zone` и выбираем  `Change visibility` > `Make public`.

Более подробно [здесь](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/setting-repository-visibility#changing-a-repositorys-visibility)

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю, что сейчас оно переехало влево.

Настройки - Основные - Уровень доступа, доп. функции проекта, разрешения - Видимость проекта - "Публичный".

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Answer (score 0):

"Settings" затем вкладка "Options" и в самом низу
"Change repository visibility"
This repository is currently public.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, что нового добавляет ваше сообщение к [ранее данному ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1080630/217579)?